# python/win32print: how to specify number of pages per side

Tags: python, printing

I'm printing text files from a python/tkinter program as shown. I'd like to be able to print more than one logical page per side (2-up, 4-up, etc). The **Nup** parameter of the printer properties is documented as controling this behaviour, but has only two values, DMNUP_SYSTEM and DMNUP_ONEUP (1 and 2), which sounds like it's an on/off setting. In any case it doesn't set the pages per sheet. `win32print.DeviceCapabilities` suggests that the usual range of N-up values (1, 2, 4, ...) should be available.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

```
def do_print(printer, orientation, duplex):
    everything = input_text.get('1.0', tk.END)
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS = {"DesiredAccess":win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS} 
    if not printer:
        printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
     
    if not re.search('PDF', printer):
        pHandle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer, PRINTER_DEFAULTS)  
        properties = win32print.GetPrinter(pHandle, 2)
        pDevModeObj = properties["pDevMode"]
        
        pDevModeObj.Orientation = 2 if orientation == 'land' else 1
        pDevModeObj.Duplex = duplex if duplex in (1, 2, 3) else 1
        pDevModeObj.Nup = win32con.DMNUP_SYSTEM
        
        win32print.SetPrinter(pHandle, 2, properties, 0)
        win32print.ClosePrinter(pHandle)
    
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".txt", prefix=None, dir=None, text=True)
    
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(everything)
    os.close(fd)
     
    win32api.ShellExecute (
      0,
      "printto",
      path,
      
      '"%s"' % printer,
      ".",
      0
    )
```